# Limit for the face width dimension of spur gears

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, stresses, aerospace-engineering, strength

As part of a class project, I need to design a gearbox for power transmission in a small aircraft consisting of spur gears with several constraints. There are relatively few parameters that I can control, namely the diametral pitch, the number of teeth, the face width and the material. The problem I am facing is that even with the lowest possible diametral pitch, the highest amount of teeth given space constraints and the strongest steel available, the bending and surface contact fatigue safety factors are below 1. I am following AGMA standards for design. The face width used so far is in the range recommended by Norton in the Machine Design textbook (and others), that is

$$
8/p_d \le F \le 16/p_d
$$

where $F$ is the face width and $p_d$ is the diametral pitch.

This relationship seems conservative, but is there any other relation governing the face width relation to the diametral pitch or the pitch diameter? Is there a limit to how high the face width could be for safe design?